# Duplicate all rows in SQL but with different id?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table like this:

```
**id**    **name**     **Marks**
--------------------------------
1          rahul             95
2          sahni             45
```

I want to duplicate all rows into same table but with different id.

Required output looks like this :

```
**id**    **name**     **Marks**
---------------------------------
1          rahul             95
2          sahni             45
3          rahul             95
4          sahni             45
```

To do this, I tried this SQL code:

```
INSERT INTO table_name 
    SELECT name,Marks
    FROM table_name;
```

I know insert creates a new record with a different id.

But I got an error:

> #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to specify the target column names for the insert, i.e. `INSERT INTO table_name (name, Marks) SELECT name, marks FROM table_name`

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
```

implies that values for **all** the columns of `table_name` are expected to be inserted in the table including the `id`, but the `SELECT` statement that follows contains only `name` and `Marks`.

You must explicitly enumerate the columns that will receive the values that the `SELECT` statement returns:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (name, Marks)
SELECT name, Marks
FROM table_name;
```

Or, you could use `null` for the `id`:

```
INSERT INTO table_name 
SELECT null, name, Marks
FROM table_name;
```

I assume that `id` is auto incremented.